# How to apply background and border to each page of generated pdf file while converting html to pdf

Tags: css, node.js, html, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I want to convert one HTML template into PDF file, I am doing this in nodejs by using one npm module with name "dynamic-html-pdf", content of the HTML is not fixed and so dynamic, I have given border to parent div in html which I want it to apply to each page of pdf file.

But its applying in left and right sides only and ending in last page .See the below Image.

[image]
I want it to apply on each page as a border box to each page

Also, I want to apply some background icon so I had applied it to body tag but for only first page of pdf it is getting instead of all pages.

what CSS or anything I need to change???

```
<!doctype html>
<html style="height:100%;">
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>letter</title>
    <style>
        *,
        *::before,
        *::after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="width: 100%;height:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;overflow:hidden;margin: 0;font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
    <div style="height:100%;background: linear-gradient(#2bd9b8, #659bff); background-repeat: no-repeat;padding:18px;">
        <div style="height:100%;background:url(https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/turtle.png)center center no-repeat;background-size: 20%;background-color: #fff;padding: 20px;">
            <h1 style='margin-bottom: 0;font-size: 18px;'>abcde</h1>
            <br />
            <p style='margin: 0;float: left;font-size: 11px;width:100%;word-break: normal'>
                India</p>
            <br clear='all' />
            <p style='margin: 0;float: left;font-size: 11px;'><b>Registration No.</b><br /></p>
            <br clear='all' />
            <p style='margin: 0;margin-top: 30px;font-size: 11px;'>11-Apr-2019</p>
            <h1 style='color: #2bd9b8;text-align: center;margin-bottom: 30px !important;font-size:30px'>Letter</h1>
            <p style='margin: 0;font-size: 13px;'>To,</p>
            <p style='margin: 0;font-size: 13px;'>All People</p>
            <p style='margin-top: 15px;margin-bottom: 15px;font-size: 13px;'><b>Subject : Letter</b></p>
            <div style='min-height: 200px;line-height: 18px;font-size: 13px;font-weight: normal; text-align:justify;font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;'>Lorem PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</div>
            <div style="position:absolute;left:35px;right:35px;bottom:30px;">
                <p style='text-align: right; font-size: 14px'>User 123</p>
                <p style='text-align: right; margin:5px 0 5px 0;font-size: 12px'>Secretary</p>
                <p style='text-align: right; margin:50px 0 0 0;font-size: 12px'>Powered by <img src='https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/turtle.png'
                        alt='logo' style='height: 20px;margin-left: 5px;' class='logo-footer' title='logo' /></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am expecting the border and background icon should come for all the pages of generated pdf file

---

Comment: I can be wrong, but the problem seems to stem from the fact, that the html document is just "one page". When you print it, some other processes decide how to break it into several pages. Try to look into either HTML docs to find a tag, which specifies a page break, or more likely into CSS. Google for something "printing how to set a page break in css"

Comment: yes @user907860 , I want the same, but page breaks happens not on the HTML part, it happens while converting into PDF, so we cant identify where page break will come, and the content is also dynamic , so how many page breaks needed is also not defined.